# Windows server 2003 deletion of event logs

Tags: logging, windows-server-2003, events

I would like to clear the contents in the security event (security.evtx) using DOS commands in windows server 2003. I get an error: The file is being used by another process. Should I stop the event collection services? Does this service have any dependency before this service is stopped?

Comment: What is the command that you are using which gives you the error?

Comment: There is no DOS in Windows Server 2003. There is, however, a command prompt.

Comment: I meant using del C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\security.evtx on the command prompt. Can removal of logs file be as simple as this. When I try to do that, it gives me an error that the file is used by another program. Can be disable the event collection and then try to remove the contents from the log file? if so, what is the syntax in windows 2003. Do we need to disable another dependent files on event collection service?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell (you'll have to [install it first](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2011/03/07/how-to-install-powershell-on-windows-server-2003-and-enable-remote-powershell-management-all-servers-should-have-this-done.aspx)):
`Clear-Eventlog -Log Security`

Or you could try this instead:
`wevtutil clear-log Security`

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/460863/218766

Comment: Can I use wevtutil in windows 2003?

Comment: I think so. You can always try and see if you can

Comment: I was using del <filename> on c prompt. Could deletion of log files be as simple as that? However, this will always give an error that the file is being used by another program. Can we disable event logs service?

Comment: I'd recommend you use `wevtutil`. Disabling the event logging service [is a terrible idea](http://superuser.com/a/288407/167187). However, you may [try this at your own peril](http://www.windows-commandline.com/enable-disable-event-log-service/)